# How can i Compile a C program on Dos prompt using tcc and tc

Tags: c, compilation, command-prompt, tcc

I want to compile c program on dos prompt using tcc as well as tc without using c editor. please give the full procedure.

Comment: have you already written the source code?

Answer (score 3):

I would look at the TCC documentation, specifically the [quick start guide](http://bellard.org/tcc/tcc-doc.html#SEC3), provided on the TCC web page. Assuming you have some source code already, a compilation is as simple as

```
tcc -o executable.exe sourcefile.c
```

You can also run a C file directly with the `-run` option, as in

```
tcc -run sourcefile.c
```

Comment: Oh yes, those compilers had the option to compile to memory and run the executable without writing it to disk.

Answer (score 2):

you can run code without using an editor by using

```
tcc -run -
```

Using argument "-" will open stdin and you can write the code within stdin and execute it on the fly.

Comment: I'm trying to develop an IDE based on TCC. I'd like to run TCC just as you said (```tcc -run -```), then I'm feeding source code to TCC's stdin. I'm having trouble to make TCC differentiate source code from standard input to be read from ```scanf``` commands later. Do you know if that's possible?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you mean Turbo C or Tiny C Compiler.

With Turbo C it can be as easy as:

`tcc.exe myfile.c`

This will produce `myfile.exe` if all the source code is in `myfile.c`.

If you run `tcc.exe` without parameters it will show what parameters it accepts.

There's documentation for Tiny C Compiler and it probably can show its usage too if run without parameters or with a specific parameter like `-?` or `-help`.

Answer (score 1):

I try the two ways as follows. Both the first and the second are ok. But the thrid one could not work.

**1. Run the script in the command line:**

```
$ echo 'main(){puts("Hello World");}' | tcc -run -
<stdin>:1: warning: implicit declaration of function 'puts'
Hello World
```

**2. Build hello.c and run with the command**

1). Build hello.c

```
#!/usr/bin/tcc -run
#include <stdio.h>  

int main()
{
    printf("Hello World\n");
}
```

2).call the application:

$ cd ./Documents/cfiles

$ tcc -run hello.c

Hello World

**3. Run the lines one by one**

I want to run codes one by one just like any Python script (>>>) on the Ubuntu Terminal, but it could not work.

$ tcc -run -

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
    return 0;
}
main()
```