# difference between the dot operator and arrow operator by structure object variable for tree creation in c or c++

Tags: c++, c

I have to clear one doubt which has same concept in c and c++ as well.

Suppose i have a struct like this:

```
struct Huffman
{
    int value;
    unsigned char sym;                 /* symbol */
    struct Huffman *left,*right;    /* left and right subtrees */
};

typedef struct Huffman Node;
Node * tree;
```

and now i create tree using tree variable. Then using dot operator and arrow operator both.
like this.

Arrorw operator:

```
 for (i = 0; i < data_size; i++) 
    {
         // the problem is here this tree pointer don't store the values for all alphabets, it just remembers the last executed alphabet after this for loop.
        tree -> left = NULL;
        tree  ->right = NULL;
        tree -> symbol = storesym[i];
        tree  -> freq = storefreq[i];
        tree -> flag = 0;
        tree -> next = i + 1;
        cout<<"check1 : "<<tree -> symbol<<endl;
    }
```

Dot Operator:

```
for (i = 0; i < data_size; i++) 
{
    tree[i].symbol = storesym[i];
    tree[i].freq = storefreq[i];
    tree[i].flag = 0;
    tree[i].left = tree[i].right = tree[i].value = NULL;
    tree[i].next = i + 1;
}
```

Now i am not able to understand that 
**(1) what is the difference between the two ? 
(2) How they are allocated in memory ?**

Comment: @JosephMansfield i just edited, that was by mistake . it was tree actually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.` operator expects its operand to be an expression of type `struct ...` or `union ...`.  The `->` operator expects its operand to be an expression of type "pointer to `struct ...`" or "pointer to `union ...`".

The expression `tree` has type "pointer to `struct Huffman`", so you use the `->` operator to access a member.

The expression `tree[i]` has type "`struct Huffman`"; the subscript operator implicitly dereferences the pointer (remember that `a[i]` is evaluated as `*(a + i)`), so you use the `.` operator to access a member.

Basically, `a->b` is the somewhat more readable equivalent of `(*a).b`.

Comment: You are very close to what i want to know. actually the origin of the problem is question i asked on this link which is still un-answered , Coukd you please help me there , Actually i was creating a tree (first using the dot operator then using -> , so dot operator i done succesfully but i was not able to do equivalent for -> operator, here is the link ) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21910872/how-to-store-values-in-struct-pointer-variable-tree-for-full-tree-in-c?rq=1

Comment: I was also not able to understand How a[i]= *(a+i), could you please explain a bit more.

Comment: @user234839: Array accesses are defined in terms of pointer arithmetic; when you write `a[i]`, the compiler evaluates that expression as `*(a + i)`; starting with the address specified by `a` (which may either be an array or pointer expression), it computes the address of the `i`'th element following `a` and dereferences the result.

Answer (score 4):

(1): The `->` is just a shortcut for `(*).` For example:

```
string s = "abc";
string *p_s = &s;
s.length();
(*p_s).length(); 
p_s->length(); //shortcut
```

Comment: i thanks fot the help but i tried to create tree on this link stackoverflow.com/questions/21910872/… The problem was i was able to do it using dot operator but still unsuccessful to do using arrow operator, could you please help me on the link i gave you ? Actually this problem led me ask this dot operator and arrow operator question

Answer (score 1):

When you have a pointer to a structure instance, you use the arrow operator: `->`.

When you have a variable or direct instance of a structure, you use the dot operator, `.`

In these cases, classes would be accessed the same way, provide the members have the correct accessibility.